# Content from JSON is not actually rendered into UI

Tags: ios, json, user-interface, parsing

This is my scenario. I start with the json api from openweather, then create a class Weather with some properties. Inside Weather entity, I create a function named `downloadWeather` to actually parse api then I allow parsed value to save in properties.

For example, `self.max_temp = valueParsedFromJSON`. Then in MainViewController, inside ViewDidload, I create an instance of Weather which is weather, call function downloadWeather, then update the ui label corresponding with weather.somproperty. The content downloaded printed into console(just for debug) is fine, but it does not render content into ui at all. What is the reason? This is my actual code:

```
var currentWeather:CurrentWeather!
    // in MainViewControler.swift
    // create weather instance to call downloadWeatherDetails function
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        currentWeather = CurrentWeather()
        let completed = currentWeather.downloadWeatherDetails()
        if completed == "completed" {
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }

class CurrentWeather {
    // this is CurrentWeather.swift where I save all the information in itself
    var _cityName:String!
    var _date:String!
    var _weatherType:String!
    var _currentTemp:Double!

    var cityName: String {
        if _cityName == nil {
            _cityName = ""
        }
        return _cityName
    }

    var date: String {
        if _date == nil {
            _date = ""
        }
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        self._date = "Today, \(currentDate)"
        return _date
    }

    var weatherType: String {
        if _weatherType == nil {
            _weatherType = ""
        }
        return _weatherType
    }

    var currentTemp: Double {
        if _currentTemp == nil {
            _currentTemp = 0.0
            return _currentTemp
        }
        return _currentTemp
    }

    func downloadWeatherDetails(/*completed: DownloadComplete*/) -> String {
        let currentWeatherURl:URL = URL(string: current_weather_url)!
        Alamofire.request(currentWeatherURl).responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                if let main = dict["main"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    if let currentTempInKev:Double = main["temp"] as? Double {
                        let currentTempInCel = Double(round(currentTempInKev - 273.15))
                        self._currentTemp = currentTempInCel

                    }

                }

                if let weatherArr = dict["weather"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                    if let main = weatherArr[0]["main"] as? String {
                        self._weatherType = main.capitalized
                    }                                       
                }

                if let name = dict["name"] as? String {
                    self._cityName = name                    
                }                
            }
            print(self.currentTemp)
            print(self.weatherType)
            print(self.cityName)
        }
        return "completed"
    }
    // the above works fine, but when called in MainViewController, properties is not rendered into UI
}
```

Comment: did you try to reload your tableview ?

Comment: Sorry, but its not my case. This is just displayed for a section, now I've not work for tableview yet. Anyways, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To update the UI you need to set the properties for your UI controls in the main thread. `Alamofire` methods are async in nature and doesn't block the main UI threads. Put the code which updates the UILabels, etc. in

`DispatchQueue.main.async {`

`}`

and it should work